How can you debug problems with temp manifests?
When I run a build, I get errors like these, but the file is gone after the build is complete.  How do you debug these issues if the files is gone?
/Users/xx/src/xx/xxx/android/app/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/debug/tempFile1ProcessTestManifest15146352796888568369.xml:27:9-33:20
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
/Users/xx/src/xx/xx/android/app/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/debug/tempFile1ProcessTestManifest15146352796888568369.xml:34:
